# Induced Group Representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Let $D_{\infty} = \langle a,t \mid a^2 = t^2 = 1 \rangle$ be the infinite dihedral group, and let $H = \langle at \rangle$. Given $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$, let $f_{\theta} : H \to \Bbb{T}$ be defined via $f_{\theta} ((at)^n) = e^{i n \theta}$. I am trying to find the induced representation ${\rm Ind}_{H}^{D_{\infty}} f_{\theta}$. I was told to find the definition of induced representation on my own (I wasn't suggested any source). I've searched through google and some books but I haven't found anything satisfactory. I was hoping someone could provide a definition and help me work through it.

Comment: Can you show that 1) $H$ is of index two in $D_\infty$ (coset representatives $1$ and $a$), and 2) $(at)^n$ and $(at)^{-n}$ are conjugates (by either $a$ or $t$)?

Comment: You may find more material about finite inducting from this analogous subgroup in the finite case.

Comment: The details of an answer will depend on exactly how the induced representation is defined in your source. And also whether you have derived some formulas for the induced character. Bob Jones's good answer describes one way, but its usefulness to you probably depends on such details, so may be you should outline some of the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition I know is: $\text{Ind}_H^G \rho$ is defined to be the $H$-equivariant maps $G\rightarrow V$ where $V$ is the vector space of $\rho$, where the $G$-representation comes from the right-regular action. Unwinding this, we want the set of functions $f:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $f(hg)=\rho(h)f(g)$, and $G$ acts on these by $gf(g’)=f(g’g).$

So first find the space of functions. Hint: it is only a $2$-D vector space. Then try to see how G acts on the basis vectors you found.

Comment: Is the fact that $\text{Ind}_{H}^{D_{\infty}} f_{\theta}$ due to the fact that $D_{\infty}$ is generated by two elements or that $D_{\infty}/H \cong \Bbb{Z}_2$? I'm having trouble defining the two functions which span $\text{Ind}_{H}^{D_{\infty}} f_{\theta}$.

Comment: @user193319 It's the latter.  The idea is to define a function on some representative of each coset, and then the $H$-equivariance will tell you what the value is at every other element of the coset.

Comment: Okay. I think I can show that $f$ is uniquely determined by its values on $1$ and $a$. This is because $H/D_{\infty} = \{H, Ha\}$, so any $g \in D_{\infty}$ is of the form $g = (at)^n$ or $g = (at)^n a$ for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. In the first case, we have $f(g) = f((at)^n \cdot 1) = e^{i n \theta} f(1)$. In the second case, we have  $f(g) = f((at)^n a) = e^{i n \theta} f(a)$. But I don't see how to get a basis from this observation.

Comment: @user193319 Just let $f(1)=1, f(a)=0$, and $h(1)=0, h(a)=1$. As a function is determined by its value at $1$ and $a$, these span the space. Try and determine $af, tf, ah$ and $th$.